# How .vrt file paths should be corrected if the file was created previously from other machine?

Tags: gdal-translate, vrt

I have a .vrt file with some SRTM tiles created from windows PC, so paths there are like:

```
<SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">Y:\srtm_eurasia\Env\EarthEnv-DEM90_N55E120.bil</SourceFilename>
```

I assumed that I could correct paths directly in my vrt file to

```
<SourceFilename relativeToVRT="0">\mnt\srtm_eurasia\Env\EarthEnv-DEM90_N55E120.bil</SourceFilename>
```

As on linux I have this folder mounted like /mnt/... etc

But when I try to make a gdal translation to tiff for example it throws

```
0ERROR 4: \mnt\srtm_eurasia\Env\EarthEnv-DEM90_N70E105.bil: No such file or directory
```

So, I use a wrong way to write a path here?

Comment: Maybe due to backslashes?

Comment: But this file was generated with backslashes automatically from QGIS

Comment: It is well known that windows paths have backslashes  https://www.howtogeek.com/181774/why-windows-uses-backslashes-and-everything-else-uses-forward-slashes/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it was due to backslashes.
Seems that from windows it generates backslashes.
For Linux I changed the path and slashes too from \ to /
Now it works.